# C#: How can I convert an array of GameObjects into a list or array of Transforms

Tags: c#, arrays, list, transform, gameobject

This is my Code:

```
GameObject[] targets;
List<Transform> transformlist;

void Start () {
    targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("target");
    Debug.Log(targets.Length);
    foreach (GameObject obj in targets)
    {
        Transform transform = obj.transform;
        transformlist.Add(transform);
    }
    Debug.Log(transformlist.Count);

}
```

I need to do this as I want my camera to point at the nearest gameobject, which I have written later in my script. It doesn't matter what I try (array or list) it still says

> "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object".

HOWEVER, my first `"Debug.Log(targets.length)"` returns with `5400`, the actual number of gameobjects with the "target" tag, so I know it is getting that far at least.

Is it something complicated or am I just being stupid?
Many Thanks for all who help.

Comment: Are you initializing transformList?

Answer (score 2):

Before foreach:

```
transformlist = new List<Transform>();
```

Inside foreach:

```
Transform transform = obj.transform;
transformlist.Add(transform);
```